# Adding CAA to pass sectigo CAA Check

Tags: ssl

I was in the process to buy sectigo SSL but i can't pass "CAA Check". It asks me to add CAA. I contacted the domain registrar but it is a dead-end. They say I should contact the host. My site i hosted on a private server running windows 2019 OS using Xampp.

What should I be doing to add a valid CAA Record?

Thank you

i contated the Domain registrar but they say CAA is not availbel domain registerar
I tried to add DNS usign this tutorial "https://www.entrust.com/knowledgebase/ssl/how-to-add-a-certification-authority-authorization-record-caa-in-windows-server-2016" but no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you use your own DNS server, you can create your CAA record directly in the DNS BIND file.Use a text editor such as Notepad to open your domain’s DNS file. Add or update the DNS CAA record info in that file. Save the zone file with your new configuration. Here's Sectigo's [official guide](https://support.sectigo.com/PS_KnowledgeDetailPageFaq?Id=kA01N000000zFMO) on how to add a CAA record.

I don't know what domain registrar you're using, but any decent provider should allow you to add a CAA record via the DNS setttings withing your account.